# PHP Post Request content contains Raw Data

Tags: php, request, field, send

I've been looking for a solution for such a long time for my issue.
But i just can't find any solutions and i'm not sure what exactly to search for.

I'll explain my problem here.
Currently i have this PHP script which works perfect and sends a successfully request and receives the respond.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.nl/index.php';
$data = array('url' => 'http://www.myip.nl/', 'verkort' => 'Verkort URL');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

But i really need help with sending a request with the following content:

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH376.png

I need to add the 3 headers and i'm not sure how to tell a field/value is empty as you can see in the screenshot.
I just can't figure out how to do this.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

**To Add Header :**

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Requested-With: XmlHttpRequest",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
```

Keep in mind that X-Requested-Header can only be interpreted by your PHP application

To send a parameter with an empty value you can do as follow

```
$data = array('url' => 'http://www.myip.nl/', 'verkort' => 'Verkort URL', 'notMandatoryParam' => '');
```

Also in your PHP code, you must do a verification : `if(empty($_POST['notMandatoryParam'])) {/*SKIP ME*/}`